# Fetch BQ metadata for multiple dated tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I know the below query works for single table but is there a way to get metadata for multiple dated tables using wildcard.
eg table1_20190102,

table1_20190103,

table1_20190104,

select table_id , row_count from `<project_id>.<dataset_id>.__TABLES__`
where table_id= 'table1_2019*'

Comment: What "metadata" do you want? Just row_count?

Comment: yes I need two columns from metadata , first table_id and second row_count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to get metadata for multiple dated

Yes, you can query `__TABLES__` using `LIKE` as follow:

```
SELECT table_id , row_count FROM `project.dataset.__TABLES__`
WHERE table_id like 'table%'
```

Comment: @Neha0908, If my answer helped will be great if you can mark it as the solution so others will be able to use this